# JS PING серверов

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем

Пол дня мучаюсь с решением одного вопроса.
Есть список пулов для майнинга, надо определить пинг до серверов. Пинг должен быть с IP пользователя до IP сервера, т.е. с моего сервера не пойдет, поэтому пришел к JS.

После долгих поисков соорудил такую констукцию:

```
      to_host ='http://5.9.6.228';
  timeStart = new Date().getTime();
  $.get(to_host).error(function (){
        ping_time = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
        ping_time_sec = ping_time;
        document.write(''+ num +' Ping '+ to_host +' OK. Time '+ ping_time_sec + ' msec.<br>' );
        })
```

Скрипт в консоли вываливает ошибку: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://5.9.6.228/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. 
Но при этом получает ответ от сервера и я могу измерить это время.
Можно ли считать полученное время временем PINGа в привычном понимании?
 Если совсем нет, подскажите решение, задолбался искать. Спасибо)

Comment: нет, пинг - это icmp, на пинг-запросы ответ дается сразу (или не дается вообще), в то время как http-запросы получат ответ только после отработки вебсервера.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. [и вот почему...](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping)

Comment: Как решить задачу? Можешь подсказать?

Comment: хм, может время на reject порта по которому заведомо reject (не drop) будет ? это по крайней мере нечто похожее (иное дело что DROP может быть по всем не используемым портам). (я считаю это нормальным способом, если нужно сравнение а не измерение) вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/qx7rR/

Comment: насчет того что ping это обязательно icmp, тут конечно ребята не правы, ping это запрос ответа доступным способом (**echo request**), существует например  udp ping, tcp ack ping и прочее, то что icmp type 8 выделен в эту спец функцию, значит лишь то, что это является общепринятым способом. Если ваш пакет запроса достаточно короток и ошибка генерируется на ack, то это можно считать **echo reply**, в примере который я привел, разница с icmp ping не  заметна. Вопрос лишь в том, что такой способ может быть неподдерживаемым на серверах которые вы собрались опрашивать, как в прочем и icmp ping.

Comment: сразу приделаю ссылку, чтобы никто не говорил что я сам выдумал терминологию ping вне ping(8) http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Ping-2.41/lib/Net/Ping.pm

Comment: eicto, цены тебе нет. Но не пошло. Половина ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, половина ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT т.к. не хотят отдавать ответ на этом порту...

Comment: @Василий Панферов ну я предупреждал :)

Comment: Вопрошающего интересует не буквальное пингование ICMP-пакетами, а просто проверка доступности узла путём обращения к нему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[На SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript) предлагают использовать нативный Image для проверки связи.

Кусок кода, из которого понятна идея:

```
function Pinger_ping(ip, callback) {  
  if(!this.inUse) {
    this.inUse = true;
    this.callback = callback
    this.ip = ip;

    var _that = this;

    this.img = new Image();

    this.img.onload = function() {_that.good();};
    this.img.onerror = function() {_that.good();};

    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() { _that.bad();}, 1500);
  }
}
```

Часть времени в первый запрос уйдет на разрешение имени в ip, поэтому для имен лучше измерять повторный запрос, когда ip закэширован.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/)

Comment: прблема в том что http запрос без tcp reject это серия запросов-ответов, т.е. проверить жив ли сервер можно, но вот насколько он далеко - весьма проблематично.