# JavaScript - пинг сервера

Tags: javascript

Как на Java Script получить пинг определенного сервера в браузере? Пробовал через `XMLHttpRequest` - выдает ошибку `No-Acces-Allow-Origin' или`No HTTPS Connection`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JS PING серверов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/319903/js-ping-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: зачем в названии и описании писать javascript если вы уже указали метку?